# Adobe Air - Blackberry app does not launch on device

Tags: apache-flex, air, flash-builder, blackberry-playbook, flex-mobile

I am using FlashBuilder 4.7 with the latest Blackberry OS Tablet SDK.
I installed the SDK and published my app (After going throug the signing process to make sure the app is signed).

When running the game on a blackberry simulator all is well.

BUT - When installing the app on the actual device (clicking on the icon) the application simply does not launch.

Any help will be much appreciated.

Koby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Never publish at the AppWorld without trying at the device first.

Either try debugging on the BB10 device - using the Flash Builder and watch the logs:

[image]

Or build the release .bar file and install it to your BB10 device using the `blackberry-deploy.bat -installApp .... -password ....` or DDPBInstaller

Comment: This is useful but doesnt answer my problem. I am testing this on the device - but the app does not launch with this error. What I'm looking for is a solution to my problem - What's causing this issue ? Am I using the correct AIR SDK version ?